# Laravel 5.5 - non-object when want call $slug function

Tags: php, laravel

I have little problem with my Laravel project, when open Blog and try to read post, view give me error **"Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/alex/Laravel/projekat/resources/views/blog/single.blade.php)"**

Files in Http folder -
Conttrolers: BlogController, PostController and Models: Blog

I have Blog folder and there is all okay (Create new blog, edit, delete). Posts find $id, and that showing me in url. Now, I want to use a slug instead of id in url. I don't want to change "public function show($id) to ($slug) in BlogController, need to keep them and create new function from PostController.

web.php

```
Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog.single', 'uses' => 'PostController@getSingle'])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');

Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');

Auth::routes();
```

PostController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Blog;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getSingle($slug)
    {
        // fetch from the DB base on slug
        $blog = Blog::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();


        // retunr the view and pass in the post object
        return view('blog.single')->withBlog($blog);
    }
}
```

view single.blade.php

```
<div class="vesti">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <h1>{{ $blog->naslov }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $blog->tekst }}</p>

        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try `dd`  at the first line of `getSingle` for `dd($lsug)` if it prints out slug correctly, try `dd($blog)` after `$blog` evaluation. If it prints correctly, Try the common way to pass variable to the view `return view('blog.single', ['blog' => $blog])`

Comment: @SaidbakR slug show me correct, but blog give me null. I don't know why, I add use App\Blog; in PostController

Comment: Checkout that the slug value printed using dd recorded in the database or not

Comment: [Screenshot database](https://imgur.com/a/ZN3yH)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read an attribute from a null variable.

To avoid this you should check it before trying to access its attributes. Ex:

```
<div class="vesti">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        @if ($blog)
            <h1>{{ $blog->naslov }}</h1>
            <p>{{ $blog->tekst }}</p>
            <hr/>
        @else
            <h1>Error message</h1>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to list from database in $blog attribute? I use same attribute in BlogController and all working correctly.

Comment: The query is correct, but, maybe there are a few differences between $slug and the attribute in the database. Try to trim($slug) before searching or using where('slug', 'like', '%'.$slug.'%') to search for It.

Comment: When I add trim($slug) in firt line, website show me correct all (post and slug url).